# Cluster Block Exception on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem in my elasticsearch when i run the method:

```
GET _search {"query": {"match_all": {}}}
```

ES return:

```
{"error": "ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];]","status": 503}
```

Comment: Which version of ES? Which status of cluster? Are there not started shards?

Comment: The version is : 1.7.2

Answer (score 3):

Well, usually it is a configuration problem, you have two quickly thinks to do.

1 - Restore your ES configuration to default, usually is here:

```
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

2 - Disable(comment) Discovery and Gateway configurations like this follow examples:

```
############# Discovery #############
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.0.1"]


############# Gateway #############
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 2
#gateway.recover_after_time: 3m
#gateway.expected_nodes: 3
```

And then, restart elasticsearch